# Confidence interval for variance of lognormal distribution

Tags: statistics

Hello I have been asked to find the 100.(1-alpha)% confidence interval for the variance of a log normal distribution.

$$ lnX_i  \sim N(, \lambda) $$

I have an estimate for lambda being and mu being

$$ \hat\mu = 1/n \sum(lnX_i) $$ i=1,...,n

$$ \hat\lambda = 1/n \sum(lnX_i - \hat\mu)^2 $$ i=1,..,n

I am aware that sampling for lambda involves using the chi square distribution, I think.